# Can you transit through the Suvarnabhumi airport with a passport expiring in less than 6 months?

Tags: transit, paperwork, thailand, swedish-citizens

I'm a Swedish citizen currently staying in the Philippines. My Swedish passport expires **20 July 2020** and my return ticket is **23 June**.

The itinerary is as follows:

1. Manila Ninoy Aquino (Thai Airways) ⇨ Bangkok Suvarnabhumi airport
2. **3 hours layover**
3. Suvarnabhumi airport (Thai Airways) ⇨ Stockholm Arlanda airport.

I'm a bit worried about the >6 months validity of the passport when going to Thailand itself so I figured I'd ask. I found this bit in the Thai Embassy, which kind of helps but I'm not sure if I would have problems getting on the airplane to Thailand to begin with.

> Short Transit to Other Destinations without Leaving the Airport
>
> Foreigners, who travel via Thailand to other destinations from the same port of entry, are allowed to transit without a visa. In this regard, the Thai Immigration Division is authorized to instruct the airlines or persons in charge of the transit to ensure that the transit passengers remain in a prescribed area. Should the transit passengers be forced for any reason to remain in the prescribed area for a period longer than expected, the Immigration Division may allow such passengers to do so under guarantees by the airlines or persons in charge of the transit.

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket?

Comment: Yeah. Both are Thai Airways, purchased as a whole. I have no intention of staying or going out in Thailand. The waiting time is 3 hours and 10 minutes before I take the second plane.

Answer (score 3):

Per TIMATIC, which is what check-in/gate staff are meant to use:

> - Passports issued to nationals of Sweden must be valid for
>     the period of intended stay.

It's a widespread myth (not least in Sweden) that airlines can make up whatever rules they like. They can't, because if denying you boarding despite correct documents, they're obliged to re-book you for free. In fact, going the other direction, you'd be due €600 in compensation as well as a full ticket refund if aborting the trip, or else a free re-booking.

**Furthermore**, if in transit in a single booking and not entering Thailand, Thai entry requirements don't apply whatsoever, only Swedish ones.

Comment: I am aware of the myth itself and it is a shame I have to face it for the first time. My intended stay is about three hours and I'm not going through immigration, so I guess everything should be fine? I hope so at least,I'm mostly worried about what they might say here in the Philippines when exiting. Thanks for the reply and clearing up this mess for me. I feel a little less worried about it and I'll just have to hope for the best.

Comment: @user107374 Like I said, check-in staff in Manila are meant to rely on TIMATIC, and should only check the requirements for Sweden. Though again, even if Thailand was relevant (e.g. with separate bookings) there would still not be any 6-month requirement. So no matter how you twist and turn it, you're all good

Answer (score 2):

What 6+ months validity? There is no such rule. Thailand only requires your passport be valid during your stay, and that is only if you clear immigration. If you remain airside, it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did not get notified. It says that on the Swedish Embassy in Thailand's page, as well as the Thai embassy about transiting. It's really confusing. I even contacted the Swedish Embassy itself and they didn't give me any good answer.

Comment: (note: not relevant to this particular question) 6 months passport validity when entering into Thailand is a requirement that's stated in many places, including Thai [embassy](http://www.thaiembassy.org/london/en/services/7742/84403-FAQ.html) and [consulate](https://www.royalthaiconsulate.org.au/ufaqs/can-i-enter-thailand-with-less-than-6-months-validity-left-on-my-passport-it-will-expire-within-6-months-stay-in-the-country/) websites. They probably don't check it, but airlines might refuse to take you.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica That's interesting. For Swedish citizens entering Thailand Timatic only says passports must be valid for the period of intended stay and a visa is not required for stays up to 30 days. The first link you provided says that visa-on-arrival users must have 6 months validity on their passports. I don't know what's going on with the second link, though it wouldn't be the first time I've seen a consulate give out wrong information.

Comment: It is, I always thought it was in the law, it even says so on [the website of the Thai Embassy in Stockholm](http://thaiembassy.se/en/visa/general-information/) (see first bullet point). I've CTRL+F'd through and English version of [the Immigration Act](http://library.siam-legal.com/thailand-immigration-act-b-e-2522/), but I haven't found it. I may have overlooked it, but it may also be one of those unwritten rules. Various countries do advise their citizens to have that extra validity, the UK uses *must*, the US uses *recommended*. I'll see if I can turn it into a question.

Comment: @user107374 See my answer. *I korthet, ambassaderna snackar skit, punkt* :)